# File.writeAsbytes() not working on Android 4.4.4 Kitkat

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I need a pre-made sqlite database file for my app which is in my flutter assets. When I try to copy it to the app's database directory, it doesn't work. It works well with Android API level 28 and 29 but not on Api 19 (Kitkat).

```
    String path = Path.join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'audio.db');
    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(Path.join('assets', 'audio.db'));
      List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
//reaches here
      await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes).then((file) {
        print('copied audio');//doesn't print
      });
    } //stucks here
    return true; //never returns
  }
```

I tried writeAsBytesSync approach too but neither works. Is there any other approach to copy my db file to app database  directory?

Comment: what is the size of `bytes`?

Comment: audio.db file is 16 KiloBytes.